# CSV Import PHP ÿþ Character

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to Import a CSV file but it fails.
When I run.

```
 print_r(fgetcsv($file));
```

I get Array
(
    [0] => ÿþA c c N o _ 1

I think the character at the front is causing the whole csv to fail to import properly.

Can someone tell me how I can programatically remove this character and import the csv?

Comment: You can skip the first character by calling `fgetc($file)`. If you need to skip more characters, try `fgets($file, 3)`. Then call `fgetcsv($file)`. Pasting the first few lines (let's say 3) of your csv may be great to understand your data and issue reading it.

Comment: This is more likely charset/encoding issue. You should figure out why it's in your CSV file, or explain a bit more about the origin and how it was processed before.

Comment: @mario I agree. I thought about a BOM if the file is UTF-8.

Comment: @Mat Perhaps even one of the UTF-16 variants, since OPs example string seems spaced out (null bytes I'd guess).

Comment: I have tried everything. I can open the file in notepad and then save it and it works. but native it wont work. I dont control the source so i am stuck with what I have but it is IMPOSSIBLE to import

Comment: It was spaced out on the php file it returned. The original looks like this - normal:
AccNo_1,MtgDate,Code,Venue,Location,Pool,EventNo,Gross_Sales,Refunds,Turnover,Dividends,Profit_Loss
66096718,13/07/2015,Harness,Cobram,VIC,Win,5,695.00,0.00,695.00,"1,373.60",678.60

Comment: What is the output of `str_getcsv(mb_convert_encoding(fgets($file), "UTF-8", "UTF-16"))` ? And the output of `str_getcsv(mb_convert_encoding(fgets($file), "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-15"))` ? (or any encoding you think about for the 3rd parameter)

Comment: It is the character that is screwing it up.